# Why my Inotify script wont go further after watches established?

Tags: linux, bash

I have made a script for inotify merge with rsync following this tutorial https://linuxhint.com/inotofy-rsync-bash-live-backups/ 
but i face an issue. It took so much time and wont go further after just showing this output

```
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
```

Here is my script

```
!/bin/bash
while inotifywait -e modify,create,delete /home/My_home/ITB/uploads
do 
    rsync -avz /home/My_home/ITB/uploads /home/My_home/destination
done
```

Comment: Did you make changes in the directory `/home/Mansoor/ITB/uploads`?

Comment: yes i have made changes.

Comment: What kind of change did you make just to be sure?

Comment: create new file and delete old one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your `while` loop backwards, you just want to trigger `rsync` when `inotify` fires, in response to a file change in your directory -- not repeatedly call `inotifywait`. You should also add the `-me` (`-m` monitor) option for `inotifywait`, e.g.

```
inotifywait -me modify,create,delete /home/Mansoor/ITB/uploads | while read; do
    rsync -avz /home/My_home/ITB/uploads /home/My_home/destination
done
```

That way, each time `inotifywait` fires (you don't capture the output), you simply call `rsync` to sync the directories.

Here is an example:

**Example Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

inotifywait -me modify,create,delete ~/dev/src-c/tmp/debug/dir1 | while read; do
    rsync -avz ~/dev/src-c/tmp/debug/dir1/ ~/dev/src-c/tmp/debug/dir2
done
```

**Create 2 Empty Dirs**

```
$ ls -al dir1
total 52
drwxr-xr-x  2 david david  4096 May  4 01:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 david david 49152 May  4 01:38 ..

$ ls -al dir2
total 52
drwxr-xr-x  2 david david  4096 May  4 01:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 david david 49152 May  4 01:38 ..
```

**Start `inotifywait` script**

```
$ bash inw.sh &
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
```

**Make a change**

```
$ touch dir1/foo
```

(additional terminal output resulting from `rsync` triggered by `inotifywait`)

```
sending incremental file list
./
foo

sent 115 bytes  received 38 bytes  306.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

**Verify it Works**

```
$ ls -al dir2
total 52
drwxr-xr-x  2 david david  4096 May  4 01:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 david david 49152 May  4 01:38 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     0 May  4 01:44 foo
```

Yes, working as advertised...

**Do a couple more**

```
$ touch dir1/bar
$ touch dir1/baz
```

and check

```
$ ls -al dir2
drwxr-xr-x  2 david david  4096 May  4 01:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 david david 49152 May  4 01:38 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     0 May  4 01:53 bar
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     0 May  4 01:54 baz
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     0 May  4 01:44 foo
```

Comment: and it even not doing rsync

Comment: Your `rsync` command is suspect. Add `-me` as the option. The `-m` option to `inotifywait` will cause it to `monitor` the directory continually.

Comment: my rsync works perfectly without inotify but when i implement it using inotify it get stuck.

Comment: Do you have the trailing `'/` at the end of your `source` path if you simply want to transfer the *contents* rather than the directory itself? It will also hang if you don't have required permissions for `destination`. (and are you *backgrounding* your script, or just leaving it running in a another terminal)

Comment: I didn't put a trailing before but after putting it, it still shows nothing. And i am using a same terminal.

Comment: If you are using the same terminal, then you must start your script with `./scriptname &` so that it remains running in the background.

Comment: now rsync works perfectly fine but inotify didn't show any output

Comment: here is the output                                                                             
sent 195 bytes  received 72 bytes  534.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
sending incremental file list
./

sent 61 bytes  received 15 bytes  152.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
sending incremental file list
./
newfiledir/

sent 95 bytes  received 19 bytes  228.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

Comment: You can control the output, if you use the `-d` option `inotifywait` will daemonize and write only to the syslog or your specified `-o file`. You can redirect the output of `rsync` as well (e.g. to `/dev/null`) if you don't want to see it.  (So you got it working?)

Comment: actually i am using moboXterm so i have terminal as well as directory list panel when ever i made changes in source directory it auto show the  output and sync it to destination folder. I think my script has run successfully. I mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Good luck with your scripting. `inotifywait` is a powerful tool. It can really make life easier for the right problems. I suspect your `moboXterm` is capturing the output of the backgrounded process rather than dumping it to `stdout` like a normal xterm would.

Comment: You can make it do all kinds of tricks. It can re-compile source code when code changes are made, I even have it monitoring changes in `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0` (to catch the monitor brightness keys and write the changes to `/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_backlight` so that my laptop brightness keys work with the Nvidia driver `:)`  It's only limited by your creativity.